# php DI container

Tags: php

i don´t have a lot of php experience i'd need some help,
i have a php MVC framework,
i use this class:

```
    class Registry {


private $objects;

private $settings;

    public function __construct() {

    }


    public function iniObject($class, $key)
    {
      $this->objects[ $key ] = new $class( $this );
    }

    public function getObject( $key )
    {

     return $this->objects[ $key ];
    }

    public function storeSetting( $setting, $key )
    {

      $this->settings[ $key ] = $setting;
    }


    public function getSetting( $key )
    {

      return $this->settings[ $key ];
    }
}
```

then i pass the registry to the other classes like:

```
    Class Controller 
 {

/*
 * @registry object
 */
    protected $registry;

    function __construct(Registry $registry) 
    {

     $this->registry = $registry;
    //i can use any class from my registry class like the logger class  below
     $this->registry->getObject('log')->write_log('debug', "Controller Class Initialized");
    }

/**
 * @all controllers must contain an index method
 */
    public function index() {}
 }
```

i start my bootstrap.php with

```
$registry = new Registry();

// Instantiate some classes


$registry->iniObject( 'Utf8', 'utf8');

$registry->iniObject( 'Uri', 'uri');

$registry->iniObject( 'Router', 'router');

i get any method like:


$registry->getObject('router')->_set_routing();
```

and i get a view like:

```
$registry->getObject('output')->_display('myview');
```

in this way i can use all the classes inside other classes
passing the registry class like DI constructor, works well,
few code and fast execution,

i've been reading about DI containers and other things,
i'd like to know a better ways to do this, if the registry gets
bigger and bigger how will affect the framework i mean i pass
all the registry to every class, there´s a way to pass just
dependencies that every class needs instead the full registry,
is the registry the best way to work with objects cos allow me
to use any class inside any other class or you thing this isn´t a good
way to do it, any recommendation about DI containers libraries,
please i'd like to recieve ideas from more experienced php
programmers to do this
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

While I am not an expert, I am currently using the yadif DI framework in my project (https://github.com/beberlei/yadif). I have modified it slightly to suit my purposes.

While the dependency injection and the registry object allows you to access an object from anywhere, I believe the difference is that in dependency injection, the dependecy object is instantiated and passed into the requiring object when it is instantiated.

This passing in can be done via the constructor or by setting properties of the requiring object.
The main point is then that the requiring object and its dependencies are loosely coupled.

As a quick example, imagine that I have a User class that depends on the Database class. The database class would return some information to the User class. However, if I am doing unit testing, I would like to test the User class on its on, with my own set of inputs. With dependency injection, I can easily inject my own mock objects (inputs) into the user class without having to set up a database with the test data and depend on the database to access and return that data to us.

Having said that, dependency injection is not a **must** or required for all projects. For example, a complex dependency injection framework may affect the performance or introduce unneeded complexity into your application.

Comment: then what you recommend if you have to use a lot of classes that can need others classes methods, i have been playing with symfony DI have you tested that regards

Comment: I have tested symfony, but I didn't like the configuration style. I am using a modified version of yadif (https://github.com/beberlei/yadif). Having said that, if you feel that symfony works nicely with your app, then it's also a viable choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting the whole registry. I suggest you should simply inject your dependency directly:

```
class Foo {
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var MyLogClass
     */
    private $log;
}
```

That way your code is simpler to read and write, and you don't have to care about your registry.

This is possible for example with [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/) which works with annotations like the DI container you are using.